# How to a show a image in a webpart

Tags: 2010, image

I created a webpart in visual studio2010 which show a few images. These images are located on the servermachine. The problem is that i can not show these images to clients.
When i run the webpart project on the server where the sharepoint site is located the images are displayes. When i contact the sharepointsite from a different machine it does not show the images.

The Images are loaded into a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` object using the following code.

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = @"C:\SharePoint\Temp\Imgname.jpg";
```

I'd figure it's the ImageUrl that's not working but i do not know how to use or create a imageurl which a client can use.

So how do i display a image which both server and client can see on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First **why the images are not appearing on the different machine**, because they don't have permission on the Server Folder... The problem will be resolved by giving proper permissions...

But this approach is wrong, you should not place the images to `C:\SharePoint\Temp\` folder, instead there are following options:

- You can upload the images to one of the Libraries on SharePoint Site Collection/Site itself, let's say you have **Style Library in Site Collection**, you can upload the image there... Now how will you reference them, you can see [Relative Paths in SharePoint](http://thechriskent.com/2012/04/02/relative-paths-in-sharepoint-using-spurlexpressionbuilder-spurl/)...
- If you want to use the images in several Site Collections, you should put them in _layouts/Images folder which you can find `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\Images\`... Here you can make a folder and upload all the images accordingly...

I am sure then you won't have the issues you are having now, I hope this helps

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by simpely creating a new Virtual Directory in ISS under the Sharepoint website. Naming the directory `_tempImg` and directing it to the `C:\SharePoint\Temp` physical path. Which was a custom created path. Sorry, should have said so. And now i can acces the images by using `img.ImageUrl = @"/_tempImg/" + imgName`.

Answer (score 0):

put your all images into sharepoint layout images folder or create new folder in layout and set path of imageurl as `"/layout/foldername/imgname.jpg"`